# How do I use a variable outside of a function?

Tags: javascript

```
function ofInput() {
  const data = Array.from(
   this.children,
   tr => Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll('input'), input => input.value)
  );
}

document.querySelector('tbody').addEventListener('input', ofInput);

console.log(data);
```

The table has an input in each cell. When outputting data to an input, the data in the array should automatically change

Comment: The function has to **return** the value.

Comment: What are you going to do with `data`?

Comment: @Pointy but even if it did, `console.log(data)` where he did it wouldn't do anything

Comment: @OP this seems more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/244849) than anything. You would learn a lot more by giving us a simple example of what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: `should automatically change` ... Javascript doesnt do anything "automatically".. Has to be code in place to detect changes and update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The data variable is inside the scope of the function ofInput. You need to declare the variable outside of the scope of function to access it. Try this out:

```js
let data;
function ofInput() {
  data = Array.from(
   this.children,
   tr => Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll('input'), input => input.value)
  );
}

document.querySelector('tbody').addEventListener('input', ofInput);

if (data && typeof(data) === "array") console.log(data);
else console.log("Event did not occur");
```